# How can I see the data in my SQLite DB in Xamarin?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin

The thing is that I´m working with **Xamarin** developing an IOs app and using **SQLite** for data persistence, and I just need to know ***how can I visualize the data I´m storing***. Just like the DDMS view in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox has a [SQLite Addin](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) - this is the easiest way I've found do browse an SQLite DB

Comment: Thanxs for the tip, do you know where does Xamarin stores the emulator's files?, I´m having troubles finding info about it.

Comment: Apple, not Xamarin, supplies the simulator.  Try /users/[name]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[version]/Applications.  Each app will have a GUID folder, and within that folder are (I think) folders that simulate the Document storage of the device for that app.

Comment: OMG getting there was hard haha, I´m new with this MAC environment. Thanxs pal.